# ORACLE DATABASE SETUP

Tags: oracle

I'm installing oracle, but the server doesn't go to the internet. I will download it as rpm on another machine and throw it to my own machine. where can i find these files

Answer (score 1):

To save (a lot?) of effort, consider downloading pre-built virtual machines which already contain database and other software to let you start working *immediately*.

They can be found here: [Pre-Built Developer VMs (for Oracle VM VirtualBox)](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html).

If you really want to download files and install everything on your own, visit Oracle Technology Network's [download](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/#category-database) section.

Comment: bc,binutils,compat-libcap1, compat-libstdc++-33, dtrace-modules,dtrace-modules-headers,dtrace-modules-provider-headers,dtrace-utils, elfutils-libelf,elfutils-libelf-devel,fontconfig-devel,glibc,glibc-devel, ksh,libaio,libaio-devel,libdtrace-ctf-devel

Comment: I want to find this and similar packages as rpm and throw them to the other server, but I could not find them in the link you gave.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about files you mentioned.